# How to order by rows according to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have this table list of records to be sorted.
[image: records]

where MAIN_NAME is the father's name,
STUDENT_NAME is their son/daughter's name. Null value if the record is the father itself,
and IDENTIFIER wherein 1 represents data is of father entity while 2 is student.

I've tried ordering them by CREATED_DATE, MAIN_NAME. But all records with identifier 1 will be on top of all the records with identifier 2.

Have also tried to MAIN_NAME, CREATED_DATE. But MAIN_NAME=ANDREW will be coming in first than Joseph, which registered earlier than the former.

I'm bit confused since the dates are all unique.

Here this should be the expected result.
[image: expected result]

The records should be ordered by CREATED_DATE but still student should be tagged under their father's (MAIN_NAME) record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional sorting:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
order by
  case t.identifier 
    when 1 then t.registration_date
    when 2 then (select min(registration_date) from tablename where main_name = t.main_name)
  end,
  t.main_name,
  t.student_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75b6011135971e630e29c35f5f709a15).
Results:

```
> registration_date   | main_name | student_name | identifier
> :------------------ | :-------- | :----------- | ---------:
> 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | JOSEPH    |              |          1
> 06/08/2019 00:00:00 | JOSEPH    | CHOU         |          2
> 06/08/2019 00:00:00 | JOSEPH    | LOUIS        |          2
> 02/01/2019 00:00:00 | ANDREW    |              |          1
> 03/01/2019 00:00:00 | ANTHONY   |              |          1
> 01/08/2019 00:00:00 | ANTHONY   | CAMILLIA     |          2
> 01/08/2019 00:00:00 | ANTHONY   | PERCY        |          2
> 01/08/2019 00:00:00 | ANTHONY   | SEAN         |          2
> 01/08/2019 00:00:00 | ANTHONY   | TOM          |          2
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However I'm getting all records with ident=2 first followed by the 3 fathers.

Comment: @ConnieVarley see the demo. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: In your demo, your resgistration_date 00:00:00 timestamp.

Comment: Your data contain the time too. I did not use the time because it is irrelevant. This does not make a difference. You did not even try the code. If you tried it you would see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`.  So, I think you want the creation date of the parent, then the kids, then in order under that parent.

You can use:

```
order by min(case when student_name is null then registration_date end) over (partition by main_name),
         main_name,
         (case when student_name is null then 1 else 2 end),
         registration_date
```

The logic is:

- Order by the "main" registration date in ascending order;
- In case of ties on the date, then order by `main_name`.
- Then be sure that the "main name" record goes first.
- Then order by the child records.

Comment: @Connie . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?  Window functions in the `order by` seems more elegant than subqueries.

Comment: *Window functions in the order by seems more elegant than subqueries* to whom?